# RedirectMatch Regex only working on some browsers/machines

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to perform the following 301 redirects.

```
/blog/ is not redirected.
/blog/xxxxx/ is redirected to /blog/
/blog/page/x is not redirected
```

I'm no expert with regex and after digging through quite a few stackoverflow posts I came up with this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/((?!page/.*)[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{1,})*/ http://www.xxxxxxx.com/blog/
```

While this works on my mac, for some reason it isn't working in chrome on my PC (reports an infinite loop when on the /blog/ page, same with IE).

I originally had written this in a more simple manner, without the `[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{1,}` section. Including this was my attempt to fix the infinite loop problem on chrome@windows.

**EDIT:** I also tested it with an online regex tool and it seems to work fine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XImEB.jpg

Can anyone provide any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browser's cache first and use R=302 in your testing.

Better use mod_rewrite for this.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(blog)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you tell me what was wrong in my initial solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if lookahead is supported in mod_alias.